# SQL Server Database and Log filesize

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We host this SQL Server 2012 database, full recovery model.
A full backup is made once a week, log backups 3 times a day.

I noticed event IDs **5145** and **5144** regarding log autogrow. Went in to check the database size and log size, and noticed the following:

- MDF initial size 70000mb, grow by 5000mb unlimited.
- LOG initial size 68000mb, grow by 2000mb unlimited.

To me something does not look right, the DB size looks ok, but how could the log have gotten that large ?

I noticed a few week ago that **SQL Server Agent was stopped** and we didn't have backups for 2 months. Is it possible the log grew and grew and grew during that time ? I guess the answer might be yeah, since the first transaction backups after I turned Server Agent back on was about 50gb !

So, what's reasonable to do here ? How can we **shrink the log size** to a reasonable amount and don't have downtime or performance issues on a live environment ?

**EDIT**

Found a related article, http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/transaction-log-larger-than-data-file/

Recommendation seems to be to not shrink datafiles, but my case is for a log gone out of control.

Comment: There is a lot of reading and research you can do on log files. Every change is written to the log file first. Then the database. If a single record is updated ten times, you get ten entries in the log but still only one entry in the database (in simple terms). When the log is backed up those ten entries are marked as 'backed up' and the space can be reused. That's how the log can be far larger than the database

Comment: in your case, it is acceptable to shrink the log file. however you need to determine an acceptable size of the log file and a log backup plan which does not lead to auto growth of log file again. See this thread about issues with fragmentation when your log file grows due to auto-growth http://www.sqlconsulting.com/news1005.htm

Comment: @ughai Thanks for that link. I'm thinking, if the LOG is 50gb, and it keeps auto-growing, and a log backup is taken every 3 hours, then what the hell could possibly making it to require it to grow beyond that massive size !